# Use PK serial column value as default for another non-null column

Tags: postgresql, default-value

I have a table with a simple hierarchical parent-child relationship to itself. Instead of using a nested set, I've added a `root_id` column so I can load all descendants of a single root with a single query.

```
create table tree (
    id          serial                  primary key,
    root_id     int     not null        default id,  -- error
    parent_id   int,
    ...
);
```

I'd like to make that column `not null`, but the value for new roots will be the root's own primary key value which isn't available before the insertion. Is there any way to use the row's primary key value as the default for the `root_id` column?

Answer (score 0):

After describing the table to see the default value for the `id` column and taking a guess at syntax, I found you can use the sequence's current value as the default.

```
root_id     int     not null        default currval('tree_id_seq'::regclass)
```